# How to get page count information from tika server?

Tags: apache-tika

I want to learn the page count of doc files by using tika server. I run tika server;

```
java -jar  tika-server-1.6.jar
```

and use curl to get metadata;

```
curl -X PUT -T /tmp/test.doc http://localhost:9998/meta
```

The output is:

```
"Revision-Number","0"
"Last-Printed","1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"cp:revision","0"
"meta:print-date","1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"meta:creation-date","2014-10-30T06:04:11Z"
"dcterms:modified","1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"meta:save-date","1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"dc:creator","ndemir "
"Last-Modified","1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"Author","ndemir "
"dcterms:created","2014-10-30T06:04:11Z"
"date","1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"X-Parsed-By","org.apache.tika.parser.ParserDecorator$1","org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser"
"modified","1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"creator","ndemir "
"Creation-Date","2014-10-30T06:04:11Z"
"meta:author","ndemir "
"Content-Type","application/msword"
"Last-Save-Date","1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"
```

As you see, there is no information about page count. How to get page count information from tika server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tika will only give you that information when it's stored in the file. Most Microsoft Office documents contain it, but a few don't. For those, you'd need to load them in Office, tell Office to recalculate the statistics / page count, then save. Once it's in the file, Tika will be able to find it

If we try with one of the test word documents that ships with Tika, then we'll see it:

```
$ curl -q -X PUT -T tika-parsers/src/test/resources/test-documents/testWORD.doc http://localhost:9998/meta | grep xmpTPg:NPages
"xmpTPg:NPages","2"
```

For the page count, you want `xmpTPg:NPages`, which is based on the [XMP Paged-Text schema](http://www.w3.org/2008/WebVideo/Annotations/wiki/XMP#XMP_Paged-text_schema)